# @media queries and @viewport zoom

Tags: html, css, media-queries, viewport

I'd like to adjust the viewport zoom (initial-scale) based on the device - a larger zoom on tablets, and a smaller zoom on phone portrait modes.

I'm able to control the zoom via `<meta name="viewport"...` in index.html, but that's not specific to each device.

Is there not a way to control zoom via @media queries??

They seem to have no effect.

I have the following css:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  @viewport {
    width: device-width;
    zoom: 0.7;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  @viewport {
    width: device-width;
    zoom: 0.8;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 801px) {
  @viewport {
    width: device-width;
    zoom: 1.0;
  }
}
```

My understanding is that the first (320px), should be phone portrait mode, the second should be tablet portrait mode, and the third should be tablet landscape.

In either case, the result is unchanged.

I'm testing on a Samsung Galaxy Tab E and an htc M8 One phone.

Answer (score 0):

I think `@viewport` is still unsupported by most browser, it's a Working Draft spec at initial definition state.

not sure if it helps but you can still use zoom without `@viewport`

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  * { zoom: 0.7;}
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  * { zoom: 0.8; }
}

@media (min-width: 801px) {
   * { zoom: 1.0;}      
}
```

this is the fiddle I've used to test it: https://jsfiddle.net/hw0xa1x8/1/ (note that if `@viewport` is supported text color will result gray)

Comment: ya, that doesn't really work.  It throws all my alignments out of wack.  Changing the initial-scale of the index.html doc is the only thing that works, but of course I need different initial-scales depending on the device.  Zoom doesn't seem to exactly correspond to that.

Comment: zoom is not the only option and is indeed a bit unusual. you can still use media query and adapt things with properties like width, fomt-size etc.  here a tutorial: https://openclassrooms.com/courses/build-your-website-with-html5-and-css3/adaptive-page-layout-with-media-queries